# jQuery .hover() or .mouseleave() not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, hover, click

Problem description:
In my menu when `.mouseenter()` the menu opens and when `.mouseleave()` it closes, but if i click a lot , the `.mouseleave()` event is executed. 
This only happened on chrome browser.

I have other `.click()` events inside my menu, but every click I made, the `.mouseleave()` event is execute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav1 li").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    });
});
```

```css
#nav1 a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#nav1 li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #394963;
}

div ul li ul {
  background-color: #4a5b78;
  list-style: none
}

#nav1 > li > a {
  padding: 16px 18px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #212121;
}

#nav1 li ul li a {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: #343434;
  width: 280px;
}
/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
#nav1 li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul id="nav1">
    <li><a href="#">Hover here and infinite click</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Stage1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stage2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stage3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stage4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Heading 2</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Stage1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stage2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stage3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stage4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
```

Try click "Hover here and infinite click" to see this problem.

***EDIT:***

As you guys said, the problem occurs in this example. 
Here is a video: [Video link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4cm_Is_EWQweU5wWkJGQ3djUzg)

Comment: I don't see the problem. I clicked on it many times and nothing happened.

Comment: _"I have other .click() events inside my menu, but every click a had, the .mouseleave() event is execute."_ well if the click events are affecting it then you need to include that here as your current example does not show the problem

Comment: Post the `click` handler... You mention it as a factor of the issue. It should then be posted. That is what "complete" means in ["Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I upload a video of the problem occurs in this example...

Comment: I saw your video. It seems like the click handle you can't post also has an effect on the accordion. Like `slideToggle()` I guess. So your two handler are in conflict. The code works correctly, but the algorythm is all wrong...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette He captured the video on this post, on StackOverflow, with no click handler

Comment: Okay then... So which browser is in use? because on my side using Chrome, the issue does not occurs

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'am using google chrome on version 60.0.3112.113 64 bits

Comment: Okay... It just occured to me... But putting **a real effort** clicking like a hyperactive on cocaine... Is that the "normal behavior" of your users?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette This problem does not happen with too many clicks; It occurs randomly. So imagine:
I have a side menu and it only has icons appearing, when the user hover over, I would like the menu to open for him to use, but when you click on one of the menu options, it closes and that experience is not good for the user.

Comment: @JoséLuiz as others have mentioned here, we can not reproduce your issue. It is likely a bug specific to a browser/os version combination, as the code you posted should NOT produce the behavior you described.

Comment: @JoséLuiz It's hard for me to reproduce, but I do see it sometimes (Chrome 61, Win10 64bits). Maybe this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/jrw37mne/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click many times the browser has lost the element reference, try this example:

```
        <div id="container">
          <ul id="nav1">
            <li><a href="#">Menu Heading 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Stage1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage4</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Heading 2</a>
              <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Stage1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage4</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Heading 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Stage1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stage4</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
```

Css

```
        ul,
        li,
        a {
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
        }

        .show {
          display: block !important;
        }

        #nav1 a {
          color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        #nav1 li ul li a:hover {
          background-color: #394963;
        }

        div ul li ul {
          background-color: #4a5b78;
          list-style: none
        }

        #nav1 > li > a {
          background-color: #343434;
          padding: 16px 18px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          border-bottom: 2px solid #212121;
          background: linear-gradient(top, #343434, #111111);
        }

        #nav1 li ul li a {
          padding: 10px 0;
          padding-left: 30px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
        }

        div {
          background-color: #000000;
          background-color: #343434;
          width: 280px;
        }
        /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
        #nav1 li ul {
          display: none;
        }
```

JS

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#nav1 li").hover(
            function(e) {
              let ulMenu = $(this).find('ul');
              ulMenu.addClass('show');
              //$(this).find('ul').slideDown();      
            },
            function(e) {
               if(e.relatedTarget){
                 let ulMenu = $(this).find('ul');
                 ulMenu.removeClass('show');
               } else {
                 console.log('fail ');
               }
              //$(this).find('ul').slideUp();
            });
        });
```

[Codepen Example Works](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzxyyR?page=1&)

Comment: The code "if(e.relatedTarget)" solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `stropPropagation` in your click event.

```
$("#nav1 li").click(
   function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

maybe the event is getting lost in the process, try to verify it, and if so set the actual element.
see this: https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/